# Vignette can't find data files during devtools::check

Tags: r, knitr, devtools, r-markdown

When I run `devtools::check()` to build my package and the generate the html file of the rmarkdown vignette, I get an error that the data files can't be found. The html file can be built using any of these:

```
knitr::knit2html('vignettes/myvignette.Rmd') # works fine
devtools::build_vignettes() # works fine
devtools::build() # works fine
```

But when I run `devtools:check()` I get:

```
mydata <- read.csv("data/mycsv.csv")
Warning in file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'data/mycsv.csv': No such file or directory

  When sourcing 'myvignette.R':
Error: cannot open the connection
Execution halted
```

How can I get `devtools::check()` to work? [`system.file`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8129485/1036500) may be relevant but I haven't been able to adapt it to solve my problem. I realise that using rda data files might be a workaround, but I want to use plain text files to store the data in this case.

Here's the myvignette.Rmd, in /vignettes

````
<!--
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
%\VignetteIndexEntry{Supplementary materials}
-->

```{r setup, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
# This is necessary to direct knitr to find the 
# 'data', and other directories that contain
# files needed to execute this document
# thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24585750/1036500
opts_knit$set(root.dir=normalizePath('../'))
```

```{r}
library(mypackage)
myfunc()
```

```{r}
mydata <- read.csv("data/mycsv.csv", header = FALSE)
mydata
```
````

Here are the key bits of my example package (the rest is auto-generated by `devtools::check` and I haven't altered them):

DESCRIPTION

```
Package: mypackage
Title: What the package does (short line)
Version: 0.1
Authors@R: "First Last <first.last@example.com> [aut, cre]"
Description: What the package does (paragraph)
Depends:
    R (>= 3.1.1)
License: MIT
LazyData: true
VignetteBuilder: knitr
Suggests:
    knitr
```

R/myfunction.r

```
#' my function
#' An example function
#' @export
#' 
my_func <- function() Sys.time()
```

R/docfordata.r

```
#' @title mycsv
#' @docType data
#' @keywords dataset
#' @format csv
#' @name mycsv
NULL
```

data/mycsv.csv

```
1,2,3
11,12,13
22,23,23
```

I'm working in RStudio 0.98.953, here's the session info

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] mypackage_0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] devtools_1.5      digest_0.6.4      evaluate_0.5.5   
 [4] httr_0.3          memoise_0.2.1     packrat_0.3.0.107
 [7] parallel_3.1.1    Rcpp_0.11.2       RCurl_1.95-4.1   
[10] roxygen2_4.0.1    stringr_0.6.2     tools_3.1.1      
[13] whisker_0.3-2
```

**UPDATE**

Following Andrie's helpful comments I've moved my csv file to inst/extdata and put this line in the vignette `read.csv(system.file("extdata/mycsv.csv", package="mypackage"), header = FALSE)` and that allows my package to pass both `devtools::check` and devtools::build`. But now it fails`knitr::knit2html('vignettes/myvignette.Rmd'`) and`devtools::build_vignettes()` and at the console with the error messages:

For knit2html:

```
Quitting from lines 22-29 (vignettes/myvignette.Rmd) 
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

For build_vignettes:

```
Building mypackage vignettes
Quitting from lines 22-29 (myvignette.Rmd) 
Error: processing vignette 'myvignette.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
no lines available in input
```

For `read.csv(system.file("extdata/mycsv.csv", package = "mypackage"), header = FALSE)`

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  file("") only supports open = "w+" and open = "w+b": using the former
```

This must be something to do with the wandering `inst/` directory that gets moved around when the package is built. So it's fair enough that `knit2html` and the console might not work, but surely `build_vignettes` should still work?

Also related: [How do I refer to files in the `inst` directory of an R package from a script in the `data` directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24397034/1036500)

Comment: Your problem is that the vignette runs in a clean R session, and doesn't know the location of your data.  You are correct in that `system.file()` may help.  Try something like `read.csv(system.file("data/mycsv.csv", package="mypackage"), header = FALSE)`

Comment: Another possible solution: Add your data as an `.rda` file (i.e. a data frame) and export it.  Then you can refer to the data without using `read.csv`.

Comment: Thanks, `system.file` as you suggest works in the console, but not for `build` or `check`. I want to keep the data in plain text format as much as possible, it's not very big and I want others to be able to get to it without using `R`.

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129485/using-inst-extdata-with-vignette-during-package-checking-r-2-14-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463103/inst-and-extdata-folders-in-r-packaging

Comment: That question indicates you should use `inst/extdata`.  You seem to have used `inst/data`

Comment: No, I haven't used `inst/` at all. I just gave it a go with `inst/data` and your `system.file` line and it's worked ok for both `build` and `check` but not for knitr::knit2html('vignettes/myvignette.Rmd') or devtools::build_vignettes() . On reading R-exts (for the nth time) I see that `inst/extdata` is preferred, so I'll change to that. I'll update my Q.

Comment: The vignette for `tidyr` contains an example of reading csv files.  Try putting the csv directly in the vignette folder. https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/blob/master/vignettes/tidy-data.Rmd

Comment: That's done the trick, thanks very much. It works for all five of my tests. Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use a file in the vignette, you can add the file to the vignette folder.

An example of this is in the package `tidyr` at https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/blob/master/vignettes/tidy-data.Rmd

Try putting your csv file directly to the vignette folder

Comment: I think I may be right in saying that, if you include the data in the installed package, e.g. in inst/extdata, it would be available to the vignette code.